# Google BigQuery Payload size limit of 10485760 bytes

Tags: google-bigquery

We encountered an error while trying to stream data into bigquery table, it says: payload size limit of 10485760 bytes, anyone has any idea of it? According to the third party integration vendor which we use to move data across from sql server to bigquery table, they advised it is an issue by bigquery?

Thanks.
Best regards,

Comment: Send payloads of less than 10 megabytes?

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the streaming limit is 10MB per request.

Row size is 1MB according to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

What you need to do is parallelize the streaming jobs. BigQuery supports up to 1M/rows per second.

Comment: Hope google bigquery can increase the per request size limit? as when the row size is big, even the parallel wont help much, as we have tried to reduce the rows per request for all parallel jobs, and it was very slow. as when a table has many rows with big row size, then it will have to make many requests to bigquery, which is not very viable option. Thanks.

Comment: @JJZ get in touch with your Google contact and ask how can you request limit updates.

Answer (score 5):

`BigQuery` has some maximum limitations and also has some quotas policies as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts).

> The limitations for Streaming are:
>
> - If you do not populate the insertId field when you insert rows:
>
>   - Maximum rows per second: 1,000,000
>   - Maximum bytes per second: 1 GB
> - If you populate the insertId field when you insert rows:
>
>   - Maximum rows per second: 100,000
>   - Maximum bytes per second: 100 MB
> - The following additional streaming quotas apply whether or not you populate the insertId field:
>
>   - Maximum row size: 1 MB
>   - HTTP request size limit: 10 MB
>   - Maximum rows per request: 10,000 rows per request
>   - insertId field length: 128

I hope it helps